# Rotate view in GIMP

Tags: gimp, drawing-tablet

**Is there a rotate view tool in GIMP?** I am not looking for a transformation tool, I want to rotate the document to make overwise uncomfortable strokes with a drawing tablet more natural.

If not, what alternatives are there to make such strokes more comfortable? Any plugins that add such a feature?

This page describes the tool for Adobe Photoshop: http://planetphotoshop.com/rotate-view-tool.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gimp canvas roation will be implemented in the upcoming release 2.10. It is already implemented in the unstable 2.9 release.

We can enter canvas rotation by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + *middle mouse click*.

Unstable releases of gimp can be found at:

- for Windows: [darkrefraction.com](http://nightly.darkrefraction.com/gimp/)
- for Ubuntu: [ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp-edge)

Be prepared to meet bugs when running an unstable version of Gimp.